# Flex reset mx:TitleWindow close button skin

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, skin, flex-mx

Hi I loaded a css to change my TitleWindow close button using

```
TitleWindow {
    close-button-skin:Embed("/../img/close_up.png");
    close-button-over-skin:Embed("/../img/close_over.png");
    close-button-down-skin:Embed("/../img/close_down.png");
    close-button-up-skin:Embed("/../img/close_up.png"); 
}
```

When I try to reload the default.css the button disappears. Can anyone help me? ClassReference(null) doesn't work either.

```
TitleWindow {
    close-button-skin: ClassReference("null");
    close-button-down-skin:ClassReference("null");
    close-button-over-skin:ClassReference("null");
    close-button-up-skin:ClassReference("null");
    close-button-disabled-skin:ClassReference("null");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer. This resets the close button skins.

```
close-button-skin: ClassReference("null");  
close-button-disabled-skin: Embed(source="Assets.swf", symbol="CloseButtonDisabled");
close-button-down-skin: Embed(source="Assets.swf", symbol="CloseButtonDown");
close-button-over-skin: Embed(source="Assets.swf", symbol="CloseButtonOver");
close-button-up-skin: Embed(source="Assets.swf", symbol="CloseButtonUp");
```